# Glossaries, polyglossia, xindy, naiive and ï

Tags: xetex, glossaries, polyglossia, xindy

I'm getting error:
`ERROR: READ: comma is illegal outside of backquote`

when executing: `polyglossia` together with `\"{\i}` 
placed in the `name` field of `newglossaryentry`

Also, it seems to have something to do with `xindy`  - as it works great when I replace

```
 \usepackage[xindy,style=altlistgroup]{glossaries}
```

with

```
 \usepackage[style=altlistgroup]{glossaries}
```

below is the erroneous example with error generating lines marked `% !!! ERROR [...]` comment:

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% arara: xelatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,onecolumn,oneside,openright]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{sidenotes}      
\usepackage{ifpdf,ifluatex,ifxetex}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} 
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,final]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amscd,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtext,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  polyglossia, etc.
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{polyglossia}   
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,polish,german}                 % !!! ERROR - when used with: newglossaryentry [...] name = {na\"{\i}ve} 
%
\usepackage[colorlinks,plainpages]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,style=altlistgroup]{glossaries}
%
\makeglossaries
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Problematic glossary entry, etc.
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newglossaryentry{naiive}{
    name        = {na\"{\i}ve},       % !!! ERROR - when used with: polyglossia 
%   name        = {naiiiiiive},
    description = {is a French loanword (adjective, form of naïf) indicating having or showing a lack of experience, understanding or sophistication},
    sort        = {naive}
}
\newglossaryentry{gauss}{name={Gauss, Karl Friedrich},
first={Karl Friedrich Gauss},text={Gauss},
description={German mathematician}}
\begin{document}
\title{Modified Sample Document Using the Glossaries Package With Xindy}
\author{author}
\maketitle
\section{\glsentryfirst{gauss}}
\gls{naiive} --- \gls{gauss}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

---

using `polyglossia` and `ï` (unicode) works as a temp-fix but I have very strong feeling that it should work the proper way around, that is using: `polyglossia` together with `\"{\i}`.

Comment: My feeling is that you should use `naïve`. Leave the old way for the new. ;-)

Comment: update - removing:

    \setotherlanguages{latin,greek,russian,polish,german}

seems to pseudo-fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `.glo` package, it's written out in different ways when the "other languages" are loaded.

### Without the "other languages"

```
\\glsnamefont{na\\\"{\\i }ve}
```

### With the "other languages"

```
\\glsnamefont{na\\"{\\i }ve}
```

So the `"` is not escaped in the first case, because some of the loaded languages use shorthands in Babel style. Thus `glossaries` acts in different ways when it's time to write out the `.glo` file.

Use `naïve`, there's no reason to stick with the "old style" with a Unicode savvy engine.

---

By the way, Xindy doesn't run with UTF-8 enabled, which could be a problem. A fix is to say

```
\usepackage[xindy,style=altlistgroup]{glossaries}
\GlsSetXdyCodePage{utf8}
```

but this should be addressed by the package.

Comment: Thank you very much, at least now I am more convinced that it is not me screwing it up :D

Comment: Do you need to load first polyglossia or fontspec?

Comment: @skan Actually `polyglossia` loads `fontspec` anyway. You need to have `fontspec` first if you need to pass it an option such as `no-math`.